# Two connections per one request

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

For the following code, each time I connect to the server, I see two connections per each browser request. What is wrong and how to fix this?

```
$ sudo python3 host.py 
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 60810)
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 60812)
```

Browser:

> http://localhost:65432/

host.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            conn.sendall(data)
```

---

Also, each time I press ^C, and run the script again, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "host.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

for one minute and cannot connect during this time. It looks like a timeout.

Comment: change another port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser tries to connect several times, that's the two connections you see.

The system will keep the bound port open for some time after the owning process goes down. If you try to bind to the same port again within this time you'll receive *Address already in use*. You can set the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag to be able to instantaneously reuse the port:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Note: there is no need to use `sudo` as long as your port number is greater than 1024.

Comment: Thank you Cornholio. My browser is firefox. Is this an expected behavior from firefox?

Comment: Definitely. In firefox you can open the developer tools by pressing F12. There is a tab called _Network_ where you can see the requests made by the browser. If I simulate the behavior of your script, I see two requests, one for the content on http://localhost:65432 and one for the favicon (the icon displayed next to the title in the firefox tabs).
Another way of seeing the requests is of course printing them to stdout in your python script ;-)